# Saving image with portrait effects matte to PHPhotoLibrary not possible?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm prototyping simple photo concepts using Apple's AVCam app as a basis. The front camera capture pipeline is set to capture and process both the depth- and portrait-mattes pretty much in a way AVCam app has done it and a high quality portrait matte is being delivered with the `AVCapturePhoto` object in `didFinishProcessingPhoto`.

It seems a bare `PHAssetCreationRequest addResource` doesn't save the portrait matte as image's metadata, as when I read back the stored image from the `PHPhotoLibrary` and peek into its metadata followed by calls to `CGImageSourceCopyAuxiliaryDataInfoAtIndex()`, I can see that only key `kCGImageAuxiliaryDataTypeDisparity` returns data, but keys `kCGImageAuxiliaryDataTypeDepth` and `kCGImageAuxiliaryDataTypePortraitEffectsMatte` both return `nil`.

**Edit**: tested writing flattened `AVCapturePhoto` object to a file and reading it back preserves all metadata including the portrait effects matte. However, passing that data object to PHPhotoLibrary asset creation request results in portrait effects matte getting stripped away.

Any idea how the matte could be written through the PHPhotoLibrary API or is this exclusive API only for Apple's Camera app Portrait mode?

Answer (score 1):

Mystery was resolved. Here are some notes in case someone makes the same mistakes when e.g. experimenting with AVCam source code.

It turned out the portrait matte was indeed written to `PHPhotoLibrary` with the image, but reading it back with `PHImagePickerController` needed some attention. When accessing the image data with `NSItemProvider.loadDataRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: representation)` the representation identifier has to be the same format and type the file was saved. For example my photo container was of type .heic. Now, even though `NSItemProvider.hasRepresentationConforming(toTypeIdentifier: representation...)` listed type identifiers,

```
UTType.heic
UTType.jpeg
```

as supported, only the first could load the matte correctly. If I tried to access the data with `.jpeg` identifier portrait matte was not loaded, but strange error

> "Could not create a bookmark: NSError: Cocoa 257 "The file couldn’t be
> opened because you don’t have permission to view it"

kept appearing on Xcode console.

The second mistake was capturing and storing live photo data with portrait matte. It seems possible, but at least iOS Photos app can't handle those photos properly in edit mode and saving the edit always fails in error

> "Photo could not be saved, please try again later."

So, don't enable live photo options in capture settings when capturing portrait matte.